# Losing elements in python code while creating a dictionary from a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have some headache with this python code.

```
    print "length:", len(pub) # length: 420
    pub_dict = dict((p.key, p) for p in pub)
    print "dict:", len(pub_dict) # length: 163
```

If I understand this right, I get a dictionary containing the attribute `p.key` as key and the object `p` as its value for each element of `pub`. Are there some **side effect** I don't see? Because `len(pub_dict)` should be the same as `len(pub)` and it is certainly not here, or am I mistaken?

Comment: If there are several `p` with the same `p.key` in `pub`, only the last one will end up in the dictionary because it can hold only one value per key.

Comment: @Sven: Yes, there are some! Thanks for pointing that out! Now I know where the error is coming from. Perhaps you want to turn your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you may have several p with the same key then you may use list as value for you key within new dicitionary:

```
pub_dict = {}    
for p in pub:
   if not p.key in pub_dict:
      pub_dict[p.key] = []
   pub_dict[p.key].append(p)
```

Or if it is neccessary for you to uniquely identify each record you may use any combined key like key + any other p propery value

Answer (score -1):

```
pub_dict = {}
for i,p in enumerate(pub):
     pub_dict[p.key] = p
     print i+1,len(pub_dict)
```

would have give you light on the problem